# Change dll References in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2012, dll, monogame

I'm trying to create a Monogame Project in Visual Studio 2012. Monogame itself is installed correctly, I've cloned one of my older projects from github and it compiles fine.

But if I create a new project in Visual Studio the .dll references are wrong. There is a build error that complains about not finding SDL.dll . There is the SDL.dll reference in my project outline and it indeed points to the wrong file:
[image]

This path "C:\Users\lhk\Program Files..." does not exist. Windows doesn't store Program files in its "Users" folder.

I opened the explorer and opened the very same path without "Users\lhk\" and the .dll is found.
Then I checked my older project again. The same SDL.dll is referenced in the Visual Studio solution but the path is the correct one. And the older project compiles just fine.

Somehow the Monogame Project template fills in the wrong paths.

Now here's the problem:

**I can't edit that reference.**

The text is greyed out and not editable and I didn't find the correct settings to change the reference.

Oh, the problem is solved:

I tried drag-and-drop with the dll.
So far Visal Studio always complained that there is an existing file with the same name.
I tried to "cut" the wrong .dll but that only made its icon slightly transparent. The new .dll still couldn't be added.

Turns out that the ENTF key can do what cutting can't.

I'm afraid I never got the idea that I could delete it with ENTF after cutting didn't work. Now its gone.

I dragged the new dll over to the project.

Compiles fine

Comment: right click on the dll and select include in project

Comment: hm, there's no such option. Maybe I didn't install some explorer plugins from visual studio ? If I right click on the dll, I only get "open with"

Comment: http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?sdl you can download this dll from here and delete this reference and new downloaded dll

Comment: I do have the right .dll . And my older projects work just fine

Comment: Actually the problem just solved itself

Comment: The solution is embarrassingly simple, but sometimes simple problems are the hardest

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can just drag and drop references to a project.

At first I thought this wouldn't be possible because the wrong .dll just couldn't be deleted. I tried to "cut" it from the project but it just changed the color of its icon and persisted.
With the old .dll still intact the new one couldn't be added.

I'm afraid the solution is extremely simple. You can just remove this reference by pressing "ENTF" - it's rather embarrassing. But I never thought this would work after cutting had no effect.

With the old reference having been removed you can indeed drag and drop the new one.

The project compiles fine.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is create a path on the drive and put the sdl.dll file there. So whenever I make a project Visual Studio finds it.

Comment: I will put it as comment and not answer